# Procedure or function 'SP_CheckEmployeeCode' expects parameter '@result', which was not supplied

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a insert stored procedure and I want to check whether the EmployeeCode already exists or not if exists I have to show an error. I hope someone can help me fix this from Stored Procedure code.

Stored Procedure code:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_CheckEmployeeCode] @result nchar(10)
AS
IF exists(select manv from LINK0.BANK.dbo.Employee where EmployeeCode =@result)
    return 1
else
    return 0
```

Code calling the stored procedure:

```
public static int CheckEmployeeCode(string EmployeeCode)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Program.connectionstring))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SP_CheckEmployeeCode",conn))
    {
       
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMPLOYEECODE", EmployeeCode );

        var returnParameter = cmd.Parameters.Add("@result", SqlDbType.Int);
        returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;

        conn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        conn.Close();
        return (int)returnParameter.Value;
    }
}
```

Error

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Procedure or function 'SP_CheckEmployeeCode' expects parameter '@result', which was not supplied.'

Comment: Comment out `returnParameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;` (that parameter is _not_ the return value). Also read up on `ExecuteScalar` and `ExecuteReader`. Also _populate_ the value of `@result`.

Comment: You have declared your stored procedure to accept an input param with name `@result` (and type `nchar(10)`), not `EMPLOYEECODE`

Comment: Also, that is a very weird stored proc. It could easily be done as parameterised SQL. It returns data only if data _doesn't_ exist. etc etc etc

Comment: Also, note the `sp_' prefix should not be used for user objects as [cautioned in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-procedure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#procedure_name). Use an output parameter or result set to return data to the application. The return value is intended to indicate success or error (zero success, non-zero error/warning), not return user data.

Comment: FYI, the `sp_` prefix is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial **P**rocedures and should *not* be used to user objects. Doing so will result in performance implications, can mean your procedure simply will stop working in the future, and also is confusing for others they will likely think the object is located in the `master` database.

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question. Actually I have lost the Stored Procedure Code and I want to rewrite it.

Comment: `return` in SQL can only return an `int` value

Comment: `Actually I have lost the Stored Procedure Code and I want to rewrite it.` Then don't use a stored proc at all. Just do it as a direct SELECT sql call.